# Why bitmap compress with 100 quality became smaller

Tags: android, bitmap, camera

I am using camera with ImageFormat **NV21** to preview, when I get NV21 data, I try to use this method following to get bytes that can be displayed to ImageView.

**FONT FACE:**

```
public static byte[] n21ToBitmap(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
  try {
    Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
    Camera.Size size = parameters.getPreviewSize();
    YuvImage image =
      new YuvImage(data, parameters.getPreviewFormat(), size.width, size.height, null);
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    image.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, size.width, size.height), 100, stream);
    Bitmap originBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(stream.toByteArray(), 0, stream.size());
    stream.close();
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(270);
    Bitmap rotateBitmap =
      Bitmap.createBitmap(originBitmap, 0, 0, originBitmap.getWidth(), originBitmap.getHeight(),
          matrix, true);
    Bitmap temp = rotateBitmap.copy(rotateBitmap.getConfig(), true);
    Log.e("TAG", "n21ToBitmap(ImageUtils.java:"
      + Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getLineNumber()
      + ")"
      + "temp:"
      + temp.getByteCount());
    stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    temp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
    byte[] bytes = stream.toByteArray();
    Log.e("TAG", "n21ToBitmap(ImageUtils.java:"
      + Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getLineNumber()
      + ")"
      + "bytes:"
      + bytes.length);
  return bytes;
} catch (Exception ex) {
  Log.e(TAG, "Error:" + ex.getMessage());
}
  return null;
}
```

**And the LOG:**

```
n21ToBitmap(ImageUtils.java:103)temp: 2073600
n21ToBitmap(ImageUtils.java:112)bytes:311627
```

So, why the bytes length become smallar?

Comment: this is JPG format compressor :)

Comment: But why when you using system camera taking a photo, you will get a big image? It's also JPG image.

Answer (score 0):

See bytes length is the size of array so each array indexes have some value again in bytes.

byte[] bytes;
bytest.length = array size;

Now your array size = 20 = bytest.length;
and each index have some bytes value. 
Assume 1024 byets each index containing.

**So total size = 20*1024 this is the actual size**

**in your case array length is 311627** **and each index have some bytes of value 
so total size = 311627* value at each index**